# Input a String Variable value to a Query Dynamically with in Double Quotes?

Tags: java

I am able to find the examples that prints the string with in double quotes, but i need to input a `String` Variable value to a Query Dynamically.

For Example Check my java code bellow

```
public class TestClass {

static String[] array = {"bug", "new Feature"};
public static void main(String args[]){

    for(String string:array){
        String query = "project = TST AND issuetype = " +"\"string\"";
        System.out.println(query+"\n");
    }   
   }
}
```

When I run this program I got the output like

```
project = TST AND issuetype = "string" 
project = TST AND issuetype = "string"
```

But i want the result like

```
project = TST AND issuetype = "bug"
project = TST AND issuetype = "new Feature"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Side note: if you are trying to build a query for real use on a DB, check [How to use Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html). Otherwise you have to manually escape all your variables, if you don't do that your code will be open to [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were putting the value string into a String, instead of appending them, try this:

```
String query = "project = TST AND issuetype = \"" +string + "\"";
```

If you are passing this query into a database back-end, then you need to be careful to protect yourself from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

For example, if one of the values in the array included a double quote, then it would break your query.